# the format of the specified network name is invalid, WCF Self Host on Windows XP, works fine on Windows 7

Tags: wpf, wcf, windows-7, windows-xp, servicehost

WCF Self Host using WPF on Windows XP Mode SP3, .NET 4.0, works fine on Windows 7, but throws inner exception on servicehost.Open()
**the format of the specified network name is invalid**.

Stack trace at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()

Multiple endpoints :

1. BasicHttpBinding
2. WebHttpBinding
3. NetTcpBinding

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is related to httpcfg requirement on Windows XP.
It was resolved by using existing localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses to self host WCF. It would require addition of port of choice to urlacl with permissions similar to 8732.